# How to delete all documents in mongodb collection in java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I want to delete all documents in a collection in java. Here is my code:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("10.0.2.113" , 27017);
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("maindb");
        db.getCollection("mainCollection").deleteMany(new Document());
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

I am using MongoDB 3.0.2

Comment: you want to remove specific matched documents or drop whole collection?

Comment: All the documents in the collection.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To remove all documents use the BasicDBObject or DBCursor as follows:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("10.0.2.113" , 27017);
MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("maindb");
MongoCollection collection = db.getCollection("mainCollection")

BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();

// Delete All documents from collection Using blank BasicDBObject
collection.deleteMany(document);

// Delete All documents from collection using DBCursor
DBCursor cursor = collection.find();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    collection.remove(cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: Whats the difference between these 2 approaches ?

Answer (score 29):

Using API >= 3.0:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1" , 27017);
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("maindb");
db.getCollection("mainCollection").deleteMany(new Document());
```

To drop the collection (documents **and** indexes) you still can use:

```
db.getCollection("mainCollection").drop();
```

see https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/remove/#remove-all-documents

Answer (score 10):

If you want to remove all documents in collection then used below code :

```
 db.getCollection("mainCollection").remove(new BasicDBObject());
```

Or If you want to drop whole collection then used this :

```
db.getCollection("mainCollection").drop();
```

Comment: Advise against using drop() to truncate a collection if you are going to keep using it.  You may get an erratic error 'Operation aborted because: all indexes on collection dropped'.  This is apparently because index destroy is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

For newer mongodb drivers you can use [FindIterable](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/FindIterable.html) to remove all documents in collection.

```
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find();
       for (Document document : findIterable) {
         collection.deleteMany(document);
       }
```