# Mongo/Spring boot delete all documents in a list from a collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

Is there a way to delete all documents of a list(List) from a collection in bulk?
I am thinking of something like: `mongooperations.deleteAll(list);`

It doesnt have to be a List tho, just any collection that i can collect the documents in and delete them in bulk, instead of deleting always single documents.

Comment: How about this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31058439/4636715

Comment: This just calls remove on each element as i see

Comment: Instead of the `list` of documents you can input list of `_id`'s and use a query condition matching all the `_id`s (can use the `$in` operator). For example, `mongoTemplate.remove(Query query, String collectionName)` method, and the query specifies all the documents to be removed.

Comment: I think MongoRepository has a deleteAll method...https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/support/SimpleMongoRepository.html#deleteAll--

Comment: @prasad_ yeh, that should work, thank you! not sure if i can mark a comment as an answer tho

Comment: @btreport repository does have it, but mongo itself doesnt. For example when using MongoOperations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query to delete a list of document `_id`s. Assuming the `_id`'s are numbers, this works:

```
List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "testDB");
Query q = new Query(where("_id").in(ids));
List<Test> deletedDocs = mongoOps.findAllAndRemove(q, Test.class, "testColl");
// -or-
//List<Document> deletedDocs = mongoOps.findAllAndRemove(q, "testColl");
System.out.println(deletedDocs);
```